# This webpage has a redirect loop rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, loops, passenger, spree

I have a problem with logging into the admin part of site of spree. I set up a subdomain 
`www.bwscatalog.bestwatchsource.com` and it works fine, but when I try to login into the admin side, I got this error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop

`www.bwscatalog.bestwatchsource.com/admin` is hosted on a2 shared hosting. (Rails 3, Passenger)

```
SpreeStand::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'products#index'

  resources :products

  match '/locale/set' => 'locale#set'

  resources :tax_categories

  resources :states, :only => :index

  # non-restful checkout stuff
  match '/checkout/update/:state' => 'checkout#update', :as => :update_checkout
  match '/checkout/:state' => 'checkout#edit', :as => :checkout_state
  match '/checkout' => 'checkout#edit', :state => 'address', :as => :checkout

  # non-restful admin checkout stuff
  match '/admin/orders/:order_number/checkout' => 'admin/checkout#update', :method => :post, :as => :admin_orders_checkout
  match '/admin/orders/:order_number/checkout/(:state)' => 'admin/checkout#edit', :method => :get, :as => :admin_orders_checkout

  resources :orders do
    post :populate, :on => :collection

    resources :line_items
    resources :creditcards
    resources :creditcard_payments

    resources :shipments do
      member do
        get :shipping_method
      end
    end

  end
  match '/cart', :to => 'orders#edit', :via => :get, :as => :cart
  match '/cart', :to => 'orders#update', :via => :put, :as => :update_cart
  match '/cart/empty', :to => 'orders#empty', :via => :put, :as => :empty_cart

  resources :shipments do
    member do
      get :shipping_method
      put :shipping_method
    end
  end

  #   # Search routes
  match 's/*product_group_query' => 'products#index', :as => :simple_search
  match '/pg/:product_group_name' => 'products#index', :as => :pg_search
  match '/t/*id/s/*product_group_query' => 'taxons#show', :as => :taxons_search
  match 't/*id/pg/:product_group_name' => 'taxons#show', :as => :taxons_pg_search

  #   # route globbing for pretty nested taxon and product paths
  match '/t/*id' => 'taxons#show', :as => :nested_taxons
  #
  #   #moved old taxons route to after nested_taxons so nested_taxons will be default route
  #   #this route maybe removed in the near future (no longer used by core)
  #   map.resources :taxons
  #

  #from auth
  devise_for :user,
             :controllers => { :sessions => 'user_sessions',
                               :registrations => 'user_registrations',
                               :passwords => "user_passwords" },
             :skip => [:unlocks, :omniauth_callbacks],
             :path_names => { :sign_out => 'logout'}
  resources :users, :only => [:edit, :update]

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/login" => "user_sessions#new", :as => :login
    get "/signup" => "user_registrations#new", :as => :signup
  end


  match '/checkout/registration' => 'checkout#registration', :via => :get, :as => :checkout_registration
  match '/checkout/registration' => 'checkout#update_registration', :via => :put, :as => :update_checkout_registration

  match '/orders/:id/token/:token' => 'orders#show', :via => :get, :as => :token_order

  resource :session do
    member do
      get :nav_bar
    end
  end
  resource :account, :controller => "users"


  #From Dash  
  match '/admin' => 'admin/overview#index', :as => :admin
  match '/admin/overview/get_report_data' => 'admin/overview#get_report_data'


  #From Promo
  namespace :admin do
    resources :promotions do
      resources :promotion_rules
    end
  end


  namespace :admin do
    resources :zones
    resources :users
    resources :countries do
      resources :states
    end
    resources :states
    resources :tax_categories
    resources :configurations, :only => :index
    resources :products do
      resources :product_properties
      resources :images do
        collection do
          post :update_positions
        end
      end
      member do
        get :clone
      end
      resources :variants do
        collection do
          post :update_positions
        end
      end
      resources :option_types do
        member do
          get :select
          get :remove
        end
        collection do
          get :available
          get :selected
        end
      end
      resources :taxons do
        member do
          get :select
          delete :remove
        end
        collection do
          post :available
          post :batch_select
          get  :selected
        end
      end
    end
    resources :option_types do
      collection do
        post :update_positions
      end
    end

    resources :properties do
      collection do
        get :filtered
      end
    end

    resources :prototypes do
      member do
        get :select
      end

      collection do
        get :available
      end
    end

    resource :inventory_settings
    resources :google_analytics

    resources :orders do
      member do
        put :fire
        get :fire
        post :resend
        get :history
        get :user
      end

      resources :adjustments
      resources :line_items
      resources :shipments do
        member do
          put :fire
        end
      end
      resources :return_authorizations do
        member do
          put :fire
        end
      end
      resources :payments do
        member do
          put :fire
        end
      end
    end

    resource :general_settings

    resources :taxonomies do
      member do
        get :get_children
      end

      resources :taxons
    end

    resources :reports, :only => [:index, :show] do
      collection do
        get :sales_total
      end
    end

    resources :shipments
    resources :shipping_methods
    resources :shipping_categories
    resources :tax_rates
    resource  :tax_settings
    resources :calculators
    resources :product_groups do
      resources :product_scopes
    end


    resources :trackers
    resources :payment_methods
    resources :mail_methods
  end

  #from API
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users do
      member do
        put :generate_api_key
        put :clear_api_key
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :api do
    resources :shipments, :except => [:new,:edit] do
      put :event, :on => :member
      resources :inventory_units, :except => [:new,:edit] do
        put :event, :on => :member
      end
    end
    resources :orders, :except => [:new,:edit] do
      put :event, :on => :member
      resources :shipments, :except => [:new,:edit]
      resources :line_items, :except => [:new,:edit]
      resources :inventory_units, :except => [:new,:edit] do
        put :event, :on => :member
      end
    end
    resources :inventory_units, :except => [:new,:edit] do
      put :event, :on => :member
    end
    resources :products, :except => [:new,:edit]
    resources :countries, :except => [:new,:edit] do
      resources :states, :except => [:new,:edit]
    end
    resources :states, :except => [:new,:edit]
  end

  match '/admin' => 'admin/orders#index', :as => :admin

  match '/content/cvv' => 'content#cvv'

  #RAILS3 TODO - we should disable this by default
  #match '/:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'

  # a catchall route for "static" content (except paths with explicit extensions: .html, .ico, etc)
  #if Spree::Config.instance && Spree::Config.get(:use_content_controller)
    match '/*path' => 'content#show'
  #end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your routes file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your server's response headers, it's being constantly redirected from HTTPS to HTTP and back. Probably something within your application controller. I'm not familiar with Spree, but can you enable HTTPS for your entire site?